# popOS on Dell Machine not extending screen to Espresso Monitor Specifically (can extend to another dell)

Tags: operating-system

I am using popOS 22.04 on a Dell Vostro machine and am having issues extending graphics to my espresso monitor. I am able to extend graphics to another dell monitor I have. However when I try to extend to the espresso monitor I can move things around from the espresso monitor (so it is extending) but I can't see anything on the espresso screen. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I have troubleshot with espresso staff and they recommended downloading software for ubuntu from their espresso site but that installation is failing.